# Does sim_slopes take into account random intercept in model?

Tags: lme4, panel-data, longitudinal

I am using sim_slopes to test whether the slopes are different for different levels of a variable:

```
sim_slopes(model6, pred = Score, modx = Age, mod2 =   
Status, johnson_neyman = TRUE)
```

The model I am basing this on is a Linear Mixed Effects model with lmer from package lme4. I was wondering if the above code takes into account the fact that the data is longitudinal and that the model uses random intercepts for each participant?

Comment: What package is `sim_slopes` from? Also, this seems to be more of a statistical question rather than a coding one, you may have more luck on CrossValidated.

Comment: It is in the interactions package.

Comment: I have read the documentation and looked at the code of the `sim_slopes` function. As far as I can tell, it is taking the information about the predicted slopes from the model, as so the fixed effects should be taking into account the fact that participants have their own intercept and reporting the fixed effect of the mean/median participant.